# Contour DEM using Python CRASH

Tags: pyqgis, gdal

I am attempting to contour a DEM raster using `gdal.ContourGenerate()`.

This is my code:

```
in_data_set = gdal.Open(TEMP_CROP_DEM_PATH, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
in1 = in_data_set.GetRasterBand(1)

ogr_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").CreateDataSource(TEMP_CONTOURS_PATH)
contour_shp = ogr_ds.CreateLayer('contour', dest_srs)

field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("ID", ogr.OFTInteger)
contour_shp.CreateField(field_defn)
field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("elev", ogr.OFTReal)
contour_shp.CreateField(field_defn)

gdal.ContourGenerate(in1, contour_offset, 0, [], 0, 0, contour_shp, 0, 1)
```

This code has worked for me on several tests, however it does not work when there is an area of `no data` in the DEM. When contouring a DEM with `no data` areas, QGIS freezes on the last line (`ContourGenerate`) and crashes.

I have looked through the GDAL API and made sure all my arguments are correct. I have tried changing the 5th argument `useNoData` to 1 and saw no change.

Running `in1.GetNoDataValue()` also causes QGIS to crash.

I am running out of ideas of where to look to solve my problem. Has anyone come across something similar? Are there other ways to achieve my goal, create vector contours from a DEM in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by setting the `no data value`. I used `QgsRasterLayer` class to grab the `no_data_value`. I then changed my arguments on the `gdal.ContourGenerate` to set `useNoData` to 1 and set `noDataValue` to the `no_data_value`.

The docstring for `gdal.ContourGenerate` is:

```
"""ContourGenerate(Band srcBand, double contourInterval, double contourBase,
int fixedLevelCount, int useNoData, double noDataValue, Layer dstLayer,
int idField, int elevField, GDALProgressFunc callback=0,
void * callback_data=None) -> int"""
```

my final code additions:

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(TEMP_CROP_DEM_PATH, 'terrain_temp')
block = layer.dataProvider().block(
    1,
    layer.extent(),
    layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY(),
    layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
    )
no_data_value = block.noDataValue()

...
...
...

gdal.ContourGenerate(in1, contour_offset, 0, [], 1, no_data_value, contour_shp, 0, 1)
```